# how to run applications using device id in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c-2.0

Hi friends I tried this but could not find clear solution .
I searched on some links on Google but didn't get clear idea how to do that.

My client is on my head  he is asking to install app using device id only.
Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: hi.. i m not getting you you want to install app. in client device or anything else you want ??

Comment: What kind of application?? The one you developed? Are you iOS developer??

Answer (score 0):

When we build an application for device it needs certificate and provisioning profile. If client wants that the application is to be installed on the specified devices and not on all the devices then you will need to use `Ad-Hoc distribution profile`.

To use this, first you will need to add particular device, on which you wish to run application, on provisioning portal.

After that you will have to download new provisioning profile, which will have entry for that device. 
Now you will simply sign your application with this profile.

Using this you will be able to install application only on those devices which are added to this profile. You can add upto 100 devices in this profile.

Here is a link that compares between different programms

https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Thanks,

Comment: yes bro u r absolutely right but i had done two steps  but didn't understand third step

Comment: @KartikArora yes i developed my own app and now clent is asking me to install that app in his deveice  and given me device id....XXXXXXXXXXXXX34r21a40tXX

Comment: so you have added the device in the portal and created the provisioning profile. Now are you stuck with the process of creation of application build?

Comment: see @Ravin its simple i just created app ok...and after that client given me device id and asking to install the app on that device and that device is not with me

Comment: In this case if you have singed your app with the provisioning profile that I described above then you will need to send the .ipa or .app file to your client and ask him to install it via iTunes. But If the provision profile does not have that desired device added in it than you will need to sing the app with distribution profile(enterprise program) and send the .ipa/.app file to client.

Comment: friends,
i included following code:
-(void)backgroundmoving:(cctime)dt
{
static float bk_f =0.0f;
bk_f -= 0.3;
//if (bk_f <= -1450*1.1) {bk_f=0;}
if(bk_f<=-480 * 1.1)
{
bk_f = 0;
}
if(bk_f ==60)
{
gamejoystick.position =ccp(0,80);
}
background.position = ccp(0,bk_f);
}
static CGPoint applyVelocity(CGPoint velocity, CGPoint position, float delta)
{
return CGPointMake(position.x + velocity.x * delta, position.y + velocity.y * delta);
}

using this code in game, my background is moving properly but in iphone 4S is it breaking
please help me

Comment: @Vijay it would be benificial if you post your problem as a question so that others who have any idear about this can answer it. And also it will make you question formatting clear. Because in this comment code is not readable. Also, mention on which device you have tested it, and what does ccp function does. If it is crashing then what crash log does it print? If you mention all this in your question than it will become easy to solve it. thanks

Comment: friends i really apologized for sending in wrong format here is right format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476782/how-to-run-applications-using-device-id-in-iphone/9476878#comment12133491_9476878

Comment: -(void)backgroundmoving:(ccTime)dt 

{ 
 static float bk_f=0.0f;
 
    
 bk_f -=0.3;
 
    
 //if (bk_f <= -1450*1.1) {bk_f=0;}
    if (bk_f <= -480*1.1) {bk_f=0;}
    
    if (bk_f == 60) {
        
        gameJoystick.position = ccp(0,80);
    }
    background.position = ccp(0,bk_f);
}